# POST Request to REST API with Apache Beam

Tags: powerbi, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the use case that we're pulling messages from PubSub, and then the idea is to POST those messages to the REST API of PowerBI. We want to create a Live Report using the `PushDatasets` feature.

The main idea should be something like this:

PubSub -> Apache Beam -> POST REST API -> PowerBI Dashboard

I haven't found any implementation about POST Request inside an Apache Beam job (the runner is not a problem right now), just a GET request inside a `DoFn`. I don't even know if this is possible.

Has someone experienced doing something like this? or maybe another framework/tool that may be more helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sending POST requests to an external API is certainly possible, but requires some care. It could be as simple as making the POST inside the body of a DoFn, but be aware that this could lead to duplicates since messages within your pipeline belong to a batch and the Beam model allows entire batches to be reprocessed in case of worker failures, exceptions, etc.

There is some advice in the beam docs on [grouping elements for efficient external service calls](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/grouping-elements-for-efficient-external-service-calls/).

Choosing the best course of action here largely depends on the details of the API you're calling. Does it take message IDs that can be used for deduplication on the PowerBI side? Can the API accept batches of messages? Is there rate limiting?